# How to install ksnapshot on Ubuntu 18.04+?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

The command below was working for 16.04 but is not for 18.04 :

```
$ sudo apt-get install ksnapshot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ksnapshot
```

What is happening ? How to move forward ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [KDE Ships KDE Applications 15.12.0](https://www.kde.org/announcements/announce-applications-15.12.0.php), KSnapshot(ksnapshot) was replaced with Spectacle(spectacle).

Answer (score 6):

> KSnapshot(ksnapshot) was replaced with Spectacle(spectacle).

Use: `sudo apt install kde-spectacle`

Answer (score 4):

KDE-Spectacle is vastly inferior to Ksnapshot. For one, Spectacle does not disappear from view once taking a picture, therefore requiring two monitors. Ksnapshot would do this automatically.

The best answer is to install ksnapshot from source.

Edit: I have found a better solution -- use Shutter. Shutter is pretty close to Ksnapshot, at least for what I need to do. Give it a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with The Dude. I tried Shutter, but KSnapshot is far better IMHO, so I reinstalled it in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS as follows...

1. Download **libkipi-data** and **libkipi11** from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/
2. Download **knsnapshot** from here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphics/ksnapshot

Then just click on the **.deb** files to install them in this order: libkipi-data, libkipi11 then ksnapshot.

It's back!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on 20.04 LTS, because many other dependencies are missing (at least in the MATE version)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kwilk's answer (@scz stackoverflow won't let me comment)

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libk/libkipi/libkipi-data_15.08.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libk/libkipi/libkipi11_15.08.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/ksnapshot/ksnapshot_15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libkipi-data_15.08.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb libkipi11_15.08.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ksnapshot_15.08.2-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

For me, dpkg also reported "dependency problems - leaving unconfigured" for each package.
Then I ran synaptic package manager, which told me there were broken packages and gave me the option to fix them. This I did, and clicked "Apply". And Ksnapshot is there and working.